# Multiple format validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a field string `foo` that must meet four conditions:

- It must be non-blank
- It must be unique for all records
- It must only contain letters, digits, and hypens
- It must not start with the string "bar"

The first two are handled by `:presence` and `:uniqueness` validations. The latter two are easily handled by  `:format` validations through regexes.

Is it possible to include multiple `:format` validation rules, with different `:message` values?

I'd like to avoid combining the two conditions into a single regex. In addition to the multiple messages, I think it's easier to read and write if they're distinct.

Ideally I'd like all of these to be wrapped up in a single `validates` call, but that's not strictly required.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [source code for the validates method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/91f8cf22647e2e102c0897e88faec049f606843f/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L81), there's no way to do it; you get one `:format` key and one set of options as the hash value.

However, there's nothing stopping me from calling `validates` twice:

```
validates :foo, 
  :presence => true, 
  :uniqueness => true,
  :format => {
    :with => /^[\w\-]*$/,
    :message => 'may only contain letters, digits, and hyphen'
  }
validates :foo, :format => { 
  :with => /^(?!bar)/, 
  :message => 'may not start with "bar"'
}
```

This seems to work fine.